# gdb: <error reading variable> with c++ vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, gdb, stdvector

I have problem in accessing the memory for a std vector.

I first define  a struct (in the header file):

```
typedef struct Systems {
//  other variables...
    vector <double>  sum;
} System;
```

I need an ensemble of system, and each vector sum must contain num doubles so, into the main, I write:

```
System * system;
system = (System*)malloc(DIM_ENSEMBLE*sizeof(System));
for (i =0; i< DIM_ENSEMBLE; i++) {
//...
system[i].part_sum.resize(num);
//...
}
```

From this point as soon as I use

```
System[0].part_sum[0]
```

to initialize the vector I receive a segmentation fault program.

If in the gdb i try to

```
(gdb) print system[0].part_sum[0]
```

I get:

```
$2 = (double &) @0x200000003: <error reading variable>
```

I obtain the same error using reserve or allocator instead of resize. I also checked the capacity of the vector

```
cout << system[0].part_sum.capacity();
```

and I sow that there is lot of space...

What is happening? Is this a problem of memory management?

A.

Comment: can you check the `size` of the `vector`? also what is the value of `DIM_ENSEMBLE` at that time? Also value of `num`?

Comment: off topic, but you dont need to do the `typedef` thing in c++

Comment: You cannot construct an array of `System`s with `malloc`. Just use an `std::vector<System>`.

Comment: @KarthikT Yes, I can check the size of the vector and it is ok (num). the value of DIM_ENSEMBLE is set to at the beginning 1 because I am at debugging stage.

Comment: Ah yes, overlooked that.. you should use `new` at the very least.

Comment: @juanchopanza . Why? in other codes it works well. I am afraid that `std::vector<System>` would be slower and memory consuming...

Comment: It probably "worked" by pure chance. It is undefined behaviour. And no, `std::vector<System>` will not be slower, but it might have a tiny, fixed, size overhead.

Comment: Thanks. What about using `new` insted of declaring a vector? It is that @KarthikT means?

Comment: I don't see any benefit in using new instead of a vector here.

Comment: @altroware using `new` the equivalent of your code in C++ ( `= new System[DIM_ENSEMBLE]`). `vector` is what you should be using, because it wraps all the details behind a convenient api

Comment: @KarthikT Sorry, I didn't get this point. Do you mean that it is not possible to mix a struct with `new` and `vector`? Why?

Comment: @altroware I believe you are missunderstanding me. The problem with `malloc` is that it does not call the constructor of any classes when allocating the memory. In your case the `vector <double>  sum;` would be in an undefined state after `malloc` causing the issue. `new` can be considered to be similar to `malloc` except that on top of allocation, it calls constructor. So now your `vector <double>  sum;` is fine. Juanchopanza is recommending a `vector<System>` instead because it makes it even easier for you by automating the `new[]` and the `delete[]` calls and automatically expanding, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your pointer tby a vector:

```
std::vector<System> system(DIM_ENSEMBLE);

for (i =0; i< system.size(); ++i) {
//...
system[i].part_sum.resize(num);
//...
}
```

You cannot initialize an array of `System` with `malloc`, because `System` is not a POD. Its `vector` data member needs to be constructed via a constructor call. The example above takes care of that.

Note that if you want to pass a pointer to the vector's underlying data to use some legacy API, you can get that via

```
const System* cp = system.data(); // or &system[0] if no C++11 
System* p = system.data();        // or &system[0] if no C++11
```

for example:

```
void doStuff(System*, unsigned count);

std::vector<System> test(42);
doStuff(test.data(), test.size()); // C++11
doStuff(&test[0], test.size()); // C++03
```

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by POD?

Comment: Plain old data (type) - use new for things with constructors, not malloc. Or just use a std::vector<System> for this problem as has been said.

Comment: thank you for this. Just for my knowledge. It is possible to use `malloc` with `System`, if this `struct` would not have any `std::vector`?

Comment: I found better to use allocate the memory with `new`, as I avoided to rewrite lot of code.

Comment: @altroware OK, be prepared to find lots of bugs in your code then :-)

Comment: @altroware I added a means to get a pointer to the vector's underlying data. Sounds like this could be useful to you.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well this is normal life ;)... By the way, could you be more precise? I have written two functions having for argument `system*` so it was natural to continue to work with pointers... Ops you already anserwed. Thanks :)

Comment: @juanchopanza Hi again. I have still problem with this code. Valgrind report a problem when I allocate the memory inside the  struct, i.e when `for (i =0; i< DIM_ENSEMBLE; i++) {
    //...
    system[i].part_sum.resize(num);
    //...
    }`. Do you have any hint?

Comment: @altroware difficult to say. I suggest you create a small, compilable example that reproduces the problem, and post it in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `malloc' with 'new' and it worked.

```
System * system;    
system = new System[DIM_ENSEMBLE];
```

In this way I am still able to use the pointer  `system` when I call the functions previously defined.